# How to prove that...?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

How could I prove that $\Bbb Q({\sqrt2},{\sqrt3})$ and $\Bbb Q(2^\frac{1}{4}))$ aren't isomorphic?
I need to prove it and I don't know how, but it seems easy.
Thanks everybody.

Comment: One is Galois, one isn't.

Comment: There are infinitely many numbers in $\Bbb{Q}$ already, so [tag:finite-fields] was inappropriate.